# Enforce Django Enum constraints into PostgreSQL Side

Tags: django, database, postgresql, enums, sqlalchemy

While i create Enum and used choices in djagno model.Something like

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
"""User model, all information related to user accounts"""

    class UserAccountStatus(models.TextChoices):
       PENDING = "PENDING", "pending"
       ACTIVATED = "ACTIVATED", "activated"
       BLOCKED = "BLOCKED", "blocked"

       status = models.CharField(choices=UserAccountStatus.choices, default=UserAccountStatus.PENDING)
```

[Django official link for same implementation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#enumeration-types)

If I open the PostgreSQL through pg Admin & update ***status*** field with some dummy text the row is updated and saved with dummy text.
[as shown in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8kp6.png)

I want to maintain same constraints on the PostgreSQL db side too.
In SQLAlchemy we can achieve this behaviour through

```
db.Enum()
```

Answer (score 0):

The *choices* attribute of CharField is only to make validation on the Django side of the application, not in the database. You can see it as input data validation, and DB constraints as data structure validation (making sure foreign objects exists for example).

If you are only collecting your data with your Django defined models, you will be fine.

If you really need to enforce it on the postgres side, you would have to implement your own custom database type. See [this part of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-model-fields/#custom-database-types).

But again, make sure you really need this feature. There are chances that you will be fine with only Django side validation.